# finding dict elements that are True

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've found a way to do this but it's not very clean

```
ema=True
hma=False
settings={'ema': ema, 'hma': hma}

for i in settings.items(): 
    if i[1]==True: 
        print i[0]
```

Is there a more pythonic way to do this?

Comment: @AntonvBR: The parens around `print` aren't necessary (and often undesirable) on Python 2 when using the `print` statement. On Python 3, or Python 2 with `from __future__ import print_function` in effect, they're necessary, but adding them to the Py2 `print` statement is misleading.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I've gotten to used to py3 I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options. To make it future-proof (py3) you could wrap the print statements with ().

```
ema = True
hma = False

settings = {'ema':ema, 'hma':hma}
```

Option 1, loop

```
for k,v in settings.items():  # a dict returns tuples (key and value)
    if v:                     # if only boolean values you can remove == True
        print k               # print key
```

Option 2, str.join()

```
s = '\n'.join(k for k,v in settings.items() if v)  # generator expression
if s:                                              # if-statement to handle empty result
    print s                                        # print string
```

Comment: Option 2 has different behavior when no settings pass the test, since it `print`s unconditionally.

Comment: `if v` is not the same as `if v == True`, unless you know that `v` is a boolean. For example, `5` is truthy, but `5 == True` is `False`. You should at least mention that you're recommending a semantic change, and the conditions under which that change is valid.

Comment: @amalloy: Mind you, `v == True` tests are generally unPythonic, since it's fairly rare that you should care about being "really `True`" vs. merely truthy. Beyond that, if you really do need *exactly* `True`, you'd test `v is True`, not `v == True`, because `bool` is a subclass of `int`, and `True` has an integer value of `1`, so `v = 1` followed by `v == True` would evaluate as true. In practice though, it's almost always better to use implicit truthiness testing though, per PEP8 "Don't compare boolean values to True or False using ==." (where it considers `is` testing even worse in general).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Sure, you can recommend not writing `== True` of course, but that should be a separate piece of advice explicitly spelled out, not a change quietly snuck into a different kind of refactor like this answer does.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using the `filter` function:

```
ema=True
hma=False
settings={'ema': ema, 'hma': hma}

res = list(filter(lambda i: settings[i]==True, settings.keys()))
print res
```

Output:

```
['ema']
```

Comment: `filter` is generally considered less Pythonic than an equivalent listcomp or genexpr. In a few cases it can be a little faster, but only with a built-in function implemented in C; if a `lambda` is needed, it's slower than the alternatives, and generally less readable, e.g. in this case, `res = [name for name, active in settings.items() if active]` is clearer, faster and despite the more descriptive names, still more concise.